# How to determine if some "rows" in an array is filled

Tags: javascript

I have an Array of objects. Like this:

```
costdistribution: [
  {
    orderno: "",
    costdis: ""
  }, 
  {
    orderno: "",
    costdis: "100
  }, 
]
```

How do i loop trough the array in order to determine if i.ex. alle Orderno´s is empty?

I tried something like this without luck:

```js
var checkOrder = valCostDistributionAssociation.every(function (arr) {
  return arr.orderno !== "";
});
```

Comment: The condition should be inverted: `valCostDistributionAssociation.every(function (arr) { return arr.orderno === ""; });`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if **every** orderno is **empty**, then you should use `.every` with a check if it's empty:

```js
var checkOrder = valCostDistributionAssociation.every(function (arr) { return arr.orderno === ""; });
```

(notice the === instead of !==)

Answer (score 1):

that should work

```
const isEmpty = costdistribution.find(item => item.orderno === "");
if(isEmpty){
    console.log(isEmpty}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter your array by the condition `orderno` then you have to just use the filter function that I showed below:-

For non-empty objects of the condition checking field:-

```
const filtered_not_Empty = costdistribution.filter(el => el.orderno.trim() !== "");
```

For empty objects of the condition checking field:-

```
const filtered_Empty = costdistribution.filter(el => el.orderno.trim() === "");
```

```js
const costdistribution = [
  {
    orderno: "",
    costdis: ""
  },
  {
    orderno: "",
    costdis: "100"
  },
{
    orderno: "5",
    costdis: "100"
  }
]
const filtered_not_Empty = costdistribution.filter(el => el.orderno.trim() !== "");
 const filtered_Empty = costdistribution.filter(el => el.orderno.trim() === "");

console.log(filtered_not_Empty);
console.log(filtered_Empty);
```

Comment: `filter` is very inefficient for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const distribution = [
  { 
    orderno: "",
    costdis: ""
  },
  { 
    orderno: "",
    costdis: "100"
  },
  ]

const isSomeEmpty = distribution.some(elem => !elem.orderno)
console.log("at least one is empty:", isSomeEmpty)
const areAllEmpty = !distribution.reduce((acc, rec) => acc || rec.orderno, false)
console.log("all are empty:", areAllEmpty)
const areAllEmpty2 = distribution.every(elem => elem.orderno === "")
console.log(areAllEmpty2)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement you can use `some` function on array to check if any empty or all empty order like below.

```js
const distribution = [{
    orderno: "",
    costdis: ""
  },
  {
    orderno: "",
    costdis: "100"
  }
];

const hasEmptyOrder = distribution.some(x => !x.orderno);
console.log('hasEmptyOrder: '+ hasEmptyOrder);

const doeAllEmptyOrder = !distribution.some(x => x.orderno);
console.log('doeAllEmptyOrder: '+ doeAllEmptyOrder);
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it:

var checkOrder = costdistribution.every(function (value) { return (value.orderno === "");

Returns true if every orderno equals space...

Point is: i forgot to reference the element with value.